# File is not defined : when create File Object with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, file, tsconfig

I write a program with typescript in node js (not an API or web app) just a console app. I have configured the typescript configuration. but when I make a File Object it give me error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: File is not defined

My Code
// .......
var file = new File(["asdasdsa"], 'metadata.json');
console.log(file.name);
// ......
```

ts config json content

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/tsc/",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "DOM"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

Anything I missed on typescript configuration.
I want to make an object of File from typescript

Comment: I have the same problem. running ts-node

Comment: node.js does not implement the File class (or FileList etc).  There are modules that emulate it but server-side this won't be an option just using node whether or not you use TS or JS.

Comment: which module I can use to make this done. @joe thanks

Comment: https://github.com/abrwn/get-file-object-from-local-path may be this works , will try

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with node `v18.15.0`. Updating to `v20.10.0` fixed this for me, and `File` was defined in my ts-node script with no imports needed.